# ffmpeg unable to record video with audio how to solve it?

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` unable to record video with audio how to solve it?

```
$ ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/audio -f x11grab -s 1280x1024 -r 3 -ab 11 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mp4

ffmpeg version N-77455-g4707497 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavcodec     57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.101 /  6. 21.101
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[oss @ 0xa500340] /dev/audio: No such file or directory
/dev/audio: Input/output error
```

Comment: Why did you make a screenshot instead of simply copying and pasting? It is text. What is this audio device you're trying to capture? Why are you using OSS? Does `/dev/audio` or similar exist?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I think screen shot give unambiguous information about problem and better presentation. I use laptop built-In-Audio-device. But I don't know about OSS and /dev/audio.

Comment: Screenshots can't be searched, they're harder to read, text can't be copied from them, they take up more space, and take more time to make. You need to see if `/dev/audio` actually exists as I suggested before. I'm guessing it's actually named `/dev/audio0` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -c:a pcm_s16le filename.mkv
```

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEV2O8C272g). Contains lots of useful information.